golang echoserver reverse proxy - problems using Director to route requests
The goal is to use echoserver reverse proxy to shuttle traffic between users and a block of devices that sit on a (non-public) VPN.
Requests would come in as https://forward.example.com/hub-001 and be proxied to a vpn address for hub-001. Any links or subdirs on  hub-001 would come across https://forward.example.com/hub-001/sub0/sub1 <--> https://vpn.hub-001/sub0/sub1
I feel like this should work based on answers like this and this.
Problems Im seeing:

If I don't add the req.Host line the root of the forwarded host loads fine but links or subdirs on the device send it into a 301 loop.

Setting the same line to fwdAddress seems to take the proxy out of the loop. IE the URL in the browser gets sets to https://fwdAddress. Similar problem if the value is empty.
reverseProxyServer.Any("/*", func(c echo.Context) error {
 reqOuter := c.Request()
 res := c.Response().Writer

 proxyEntry = &httputil.ReverseProxy{
   Director: func(req *http.Request) {
   // this fn splits the url into the 'https://vpn IP' and everything after that
         fwdId, pathRemainder := getFwdId(req.RequestURI)
         target, _ := url.Parse("https://" + fwdAddress)
         req.URL.Scheme = target.Scheme
         req.URL.Host = fwdAddress
         req.URL.Path = "/" + pathRemainder
         req.Host = ""
  }
}    

proxyEntry.ServeHTTP(res, reqOuter)



Anyway - Ive been staring at this for days. I suspect the answer is a UFU.

As it turns out - the process for loading a folder is a 301 followed by looking for index.html (or whatever file) in said folder.
So if the link is just a path the code would be:
req.URL.Path = "/" + pathRemainder + "/"

